# Make a div vertically scollable inside another div using scrollTop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar, scrolltop

I have a div `#container` inside another div `.bloc_1_medias`.

`#container` height is larger than one of `.bloc_1_medias`.

I would like to make the `#container` div scroll inside my `.bloc_1_medias` using `scrollTop` when clicking on my text "next" and "previous" with a fixed gap.

I want also the scroll bar of the `.bloc_1_medias` to be hidden.

Here is my js:

```
$('#next_nav').click(function () {
    $( "#container" ).animate({
        scrollTop: '+=156px'
    });
});

$('#prev_nav').click(function () {
    $( "#container" ).animate({
        scrollTop: '-=156px'
    });
});
```

And a here is a JSFidlle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aaWLJ/6/

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Is it necessary to do it with just with scrollTop, or would you also accept other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should animate parent container `scrollTop`:

```
$(".bloc_1_medias").animate({
    scrollTop: '+=156px'
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/aaWLJ/7/